# react-native profiling doesn't show JS thread

Tags: react-native, profiling, trace

I followed the official guide to profile my JS: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-ui-performance.html

But when I get the results, there's no js-related code I can look at:

[image: profiling screenshot]

Any idea what happened ? The interface is pretty sluggish, cusuming 100% of a CPU, but I get no infos why.

EDIT: looks like using the latest react-native version could solve that, I'm using `0.30.0` and looks like some related changes were introduced around `0.34.0`

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use the chrome profiler over `debuggerWorker.js` while debugging:

[image: chrome profiler screenshot]

Profiling while debugging won't give you the most accurate results so be careful.