# Profiler in react-native broken (V8 and systrace)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I would like to see, which function is keeping my JS thread the most busy. But in any profiling option I just cant see any JS related stuff.

### 1) Profiling

The most useful would be the [V8 profiler](https://v8.dev/docs/profile), which is accessible in debug mode (in Chrome DevTools or React Native Debugger). Somebody [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40615339/671880) suggests to look for `debuggerWorker.js`, but in my Profiling session this thread is missing.

[image: RND profiling threads]

### 2) Systrace

I found the JS thread (`mqt_js`), but it is collapsed and cant be drilled into. Any ideas?
I run `systrace.py --time=20 -o trace.html sched gfx view -a com.my.rnapp`

[image: systrace]

### 3) RN "Enable Sampling Profiler"

I even tried the (undocumented) "Enable Sampling Profiler" option in RN debug menu, it seems working, and shows a message with trace location, but file is unfortunately empty everytime. (eg. `/data/user/0/com.my.rnapp/cache/sampling-profiler-trace119834863.cpuprofile`). Checked using `adb shell` and `ls -la`.

[image: Enable Sampling Profiler]

### Other info:

- tested both dev/prod versions, local metro bundler/bundled app
- React Native 0.61.1
- Emulator with Android API 25 (physical device as well)
- macOS 10.14

Comment: I opened an issue about systrace being broken over 6 months ago and it's being ignored. If you add your comment and thumbs up it might get some attention. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26032

Comment: thanks, there was some communication on the issue since. Seems they know about it. I liked your comment. I dont write "me too" comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

ad (1) ok - it seems you have to hit "Run profiling", and then **reload the APP** (`rr`). Only then `RNDebuggerWorker.js` appears. Wicked.

[image: Worker thread -- RNDebuggerWorker]